# JNDI: How to use Logical not query to search LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, ldap-query

I am facing problem while applying logical not query.

For example,

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results =
    context.search("ou=people,dc=example,dc=com", "sn=Kumaran", searcCon);
```

Above statement is working absolutely fine, it is returning all the person entries whose sn is Kumaran.

Suppose that I change the statement to get all the person entries whose sn is **not** Kumaran.

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results =
   context.search("ou=people,dc=example,dc=com", "(!sn=Kumaran)", searcCon);
```

I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: Unbalanced parenthesis; remaining name 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Filter.findRightParen(Filter.java:694)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Filter.encodeFilterList(Filter.java:733)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Filter.encodeComplexFilter(Filter.java:657)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Filter.encodeFilter(Filter.java:118)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Filter.encodeFilterString(Filter.java:74)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.search(LdapClient.java:548)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.doSearch(LdapCtx.java:1985)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1844)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1769)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:341)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267)
    at jndi_tutorial.Test.getPeopleSnIsKumaran(Test.java:34)
    at jndi_tutorial.Test.main(Test.java:62)
```

Following is my code

```
public static void printResults(NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results)
            throws NamingException {
        while (results.hasMoreElements()) {
            SearchResult res = results.next();
            Attributes atbs = res.getAttributes();
            Attribute nameAttr = atbs.get("cn");
            String name = (String) nameAttr.get();

            Attribute descriptionAtr = atbs.get("description");
            String description = (String) descriptionAtr.get();
            System.out.println(description);

            System.out.println("Name is :" + name + ",description is :"
                    + description);

        }
    }

/* Get all people whose sn is not equal to Kumaran */
    public static void getAllExcludeKumaran() throws NamingException {
        SearchControls searcCon = new SearchControls();
        searcCon.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = context.search(
                "ou=people,dc=example,dc=com", "(!(sn=Kumaran))", searcCon);
        printResults(results);
    }
```

**Reference**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try to add parenthesis `(!(sn=Kumaran))`

**UPDATE:**

Try this

```
...
SearchControls searcCon = new SearchControls();
String[] attributeFilter = { "cn", "description" };
searcCon.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
searcCon.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
...
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion. It is working. Only problem I am facing is, I am able to get the information associated with description attribute. but when i query for the attribute cn, I am getting NullPointerException. Is there any link between sn and cn?

Comment: I am using Apache Directory Studio

Comment: I need to see all your code to answer. Maybe you need to explicitly specify the attributes that you need.

Comment: Still getting NullPointerException

Comment: One strange thing is, it is giving all the attributes information including cn, for the query "NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = context.search("ou=people,dc=example,dc=com", "sn=Kumaran", searcCon);". Here I am not used logical not (!), I just searched for all people, where sn = Kumaran.

Answer (score 0):

See RFC 2254:

> filter ::= "(" filtercomp ")"
>
> not ::= "!" filter

Your code should be like

```
context.search("ou=people,dc=example,dc=com", "((!sn=Kumaran))", searcCon);
```

It should work for you.